# Multiple validations rule in v-text-field

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to perform multiple validations on a field in vuetify, for example the identity field must have 11 characters, and all must be numeric, I am using this code but it validates the quantity and if it is numeric or not only in the first character that is written.Could you guide me how to solve this problem?

This is part of the code that I am using

```
       <v-col cols="4" sm="4" md="4">
        <v-text-field
          label="Identidad*"  
          v-model.number="editedItem.identidad"
          :rules ='inputidentidadrules'
          counter="11"
          error-count="2"
          required/>
     </v-col>

.......
 export default {
         data: () => { 
           return {
            dialog: false,
            search: '',
            isFormValid: false,
       inputidentidadrules:[
                (v) => v.toString().length >=11 || 'Longitud 11 caracteres',
                (v) => !isNaN(parseFloat(v)) || 'El valor debe ser numérico'
             ],
.......
```

Comment: Try to add a working example of code on codepen / code sandbox! which will help to debug

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule and remove .number from v-model ie use v-model="editedItem.identidad"

```
         inputidentidadrules:[
            (v) => /^\d+$/.test(v)||'El valor debe ser numérico',
            (v) => (v && v.length > 10) || 'Longitud 11 caracteres'
         ],
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, I was able to solve combining part of your solution with that of @hardik

Answer (score 0):

try this one below rule is related to checking for valid 11 digit

```
inputidentidadrules:[(v) => /^\d{11}$/.test(v) || 'Enter valid 11 digit']
```

Comment: Thank you very much I found your answer useful